# How to use Eclipse Console output with LibreOfficeCalc?

Tags: java, eclipse, console, formatting, libreoffice

If I just `System.out.println("a" + "," + 1 + "," + 2);` and copy the output and paste that to LibreOfficeCalc to draw some graphs, they all get pasted into the same cell which makes it unusable. But when I write the same output to a file and copy paste that then I can choose `,` as the delimiter and the values will be gone to different cells.

So why it's not working when you copy it from the eclipse console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens only with LO Calc. I checked that it works fine with MS Excel. So potentially something wrong with LO Calc.